# AB = Identity matrix; matrices; determinants; proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, determinant

Let $M(n\times n, \mathbb Z)$ be the set of all $n\times n$- matrices with integer coefficients, and a matrix $A \in M$.

Proof, that:
There is exactly one matrix $B \in M(n\times n, \mathbb Z)$ with $AB = I_n$, if $\det(A)=\pm1$.

I don't know how to start with this proof...Can you help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\det(A)=\pm 1$ then $A$ is invertible and

$$A^{-1}=\frac1{\det(A)}\operatorname{adj}(A)$$
where $\operatorname{adj}(A)$  is the [adjugate matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) which is the transpose of the cofactor matrix so its entries are integers. The unicity of $B$ comes from the unicity of the inverse of an invertible matrix.